# Apply function 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

cause I don't really understand why it works in one format and doesn't work in another.

**Works:**

```
df['team'] = df['team'].str.extract(r'(\w+)+')
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
def clear_teams(gr):
    return gr.str.extract(r'(\w+)+')
        
df['team'] = df['team'].apply(clear_teams)
```

**I  recive an error:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Why it doesn't work, can someone explain it to me ? pleas :)
How it has str attribute one time and another doesn't ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) then in function `gr` is scalar, function loop by element of Series. So cannot use Series functions for it like `str.extract`, but solution for processing by scalars:

```
def clear_teams(gr):
    try:
        return re.search(r'(\w+)+', text).group(1)
    except:
        return np.nan   

df['team'] = df['team'].apply(clear_teams)
```

If use [`Series.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pipe.html) then `gr` is `Series`, co all working correct:

```
def clear_teams(gr):
    return gr.str.extract(r'(\w+)+')

df['team'] = df['team'].pipe(clear_teams)
```

Or:

```
df['team'] = clear_teams(df['team'])
```

Comment: But why it doesn't work with apply ?